# Alternative to collapse with group in Solr 9

Tags: solr, lucene

Using Solr 7.1 (master/slave) in production right now.

We use group query to group on `query_type` field, and collapse on a `xyz_id` field so that we get unique `xyz_id`s in each group (nullPolicy: expand).

I want to migrate to Solr 9 (master/slave) but seems like using collapse with group is deprecated.

How can I replicate the same usecase without using sub-queries, without changing sort order and without impacting performance/latency?